# Rails Deploy Access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano

We have a large centralized Rails app, and are beginning to hire outside developers to build small apps on top of our API. We'll be hosting those apps on a VPS running Ubuntu, and I'm wondering what's the best way to manage deploy permissions. We'd like to allow developers to deploy to our staging server, but not to have access to any of the other apps that live there.

Is a chroot jail pretty much our only option? In theory, I'd prefer that folks couldn't even log in to the server--just deploy to it.

I know something like [limiting users to SFTP](http://solderintheveins.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-sftp-only-account-how-to/) could work, but Capistrano 3 doesn't seem play nice with SFTP.

What do other folks do in this situation? Is it pretty non-standard to grant deploy access to a staging server in this case? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's a staging server… does it really matter if they have access?  But assuming it does I would setup a single "deploy server" that was responsible for deploying.  Then wire up a front end to it that your developers can initiate deploys based on permissions you've setup.

I don't have a concrete example, but I'm thinking similar to the "deploy on continuous integration test success" features you see and the "deploy from your Slack chatroom" stuff.

Same idea.

Comment: Interesting idea. Probably a bit more work than we're prepared to commit at this stage. The access issue is that we don't want to grant access to all of our code, which would be completely exposed on the server otherwise. We're also using .env files at the moment, which they would also have access to, thought I know there are other solutions to that on production servers.